# While setting up Active Admin on ruby on rails 4 and generating an "Orders" resource I get "uninitialized constant Orders (NameError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

While setting up Active Admin and running the resource generate an Admin page for `orders ( $> rails generate active_admin:resource Orders )` .

I get this warning when I try and run the rails server

```
/Users/Kenneth/Desktop/U2K/app/admin/orders.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Orders (NameError)
```

And this warning when I try and rake db:migrate

```
uninitialized constant Orders
/Users/Kenneth/Desktop/U2K/app/admin/orders.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

I do not know what is wrong. I think that the admin/orders page is not set up. Does anyone know how to set up the pages in order to avoid these errors on ruby on rails 4? I have looked through their documentation and I have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the corresponding app/**model**/order.rb?

I believe you'll also need to change app/admin/orders.rb -> order.rb
And change line 1 in app/admin/order.rb to be singular, not plural.

So:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do 
...
```

Comment: I tried that and nothing has changed. The reason that it has the name "Orders" is because that is what I generated (rails generate active_admin:resource Orders ) and I do have a app/admin/orders.rb. I do not have an app/model/order.rb. I still get the "top (required)>': uninitialized constant Orders (NameError)" error.

Comment: in app/admin/orders.rb, do you have class Orders; end?

If so, I would try converting everything as singular to see if that works.

Comment: @KennethKebaara The problem is you ran `rails generate active_admin:resource Orders` instead of `rails generate active_admin:resource Order`. Rails models are singular, not plural.

Answer (score 0):

You must create model first if your model name is
**`rails g model Order model_no:integer`** then use same name with model like **`rails g active_admin:resource Order`** and resource name always singular form.